# How can an ext4 partition automatically be mounted to /var directory on system start?

Tags: mount, ext4

Is there a way to ensure that a new partition with an ext4 file system is automatically mounted at boot to the /var directory?

Comment: Why would you mount it to /var ? Typically partitions should be under /mnt or /media/partition_name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute : `sudo blkid` ... search for the UUID of the partition you want to be mounted automatically when booting the operating system. Now add an entry to the `fstab` file.
Open a terminal and execute : `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`. Add the UUID from `blkid` command.

Example :

```
sudo blkid  

/dev/sda1: LABEL="data" UUID="5B9C797F2C733C9B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e5c27785-4883-42d7-bd79-e27109e9f3a1"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="media" UUID="066265146F41F90F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0de341ec-9dda-485a-8fe6-6603e10913a9"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="rescue" UUID="4D244C6A5C3C5310" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e9d08be2-d5b0-4bbd-aef4-330414b7b3ba"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="system" UUID="126F544516701913" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="819cbefb-c483-41ea-a6ca-970ba757e608"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="7381-B73F" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4af6ebbc-eb8d-4cbe-af28-de7ac03b0c37"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="4ccb0a38-686c-4045-bf53-5ad7a1fa7d90" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="04188846-f2b0-44de-b19d-6a7d761aba68"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="057d688c-008b-4682-aabf-ee2e0762fc26" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="80298a8b-cc2a-4798-b9ef-ecd2bb474e79"
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="virtual" UUID="65077e7a-4bd6-47ea-8014-01e06655cc31" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="99807be9-fa3e-451e-b2a9-c95ebb0b2c8e"
```

In the example `sdb4` shall be mounted to `/var` directory on system start - this has to be added :

```
UUID=65077e7a-4bd6-47ea-8014-01e06655cc31  /var/virtual       ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Save the changes you have made ... and now afterwards the `fstab` file will have to look like this :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=057d688c-008b-4682-aabf-ee2e0762fc26 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=7381-B73F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=4ccb0a38-686c-4045-bf53-5ad7a1fa7d90 none            swap    sw              0       0
#
UUID=65077e7a-4bd6-47ea-8014-01e06655cc31  /var/virtual       ext4    defaults        0       2
```

You can use the `nano` command line editor as well, but when you want to use a GUI editor, open gedit with the `gksudo` command. In case it is not already installed, open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Note : The default mount directory is `/media/<user>/<partition-label>`. You may want to consider mounting the partition to this directory instead, or alternatively to `/mnt` directory.